# Create 2 sheets with data from a column with an unknown number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

Create 2 sheets with data from a column with an unknown number of rows. 1 sheet of 50% of the rows with the largest values, 2 sheet of the remaining 50%

```
Sub sber()

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Офисы с большими расходами"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Офисы с меньшими расходами"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the data contiguous? Is it sorted?

Answer (score 1):

### Split Worksheet in Half: Higher and Lower Values

[image]

```vb
Sub SplitByExpenses()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Offices"
    Const FIRST_EXPENSES_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "E4"
    
    Const HI_NAME As String = "Offices with high expenses"
    Const LO_NAME As String = "Offices with low expenses"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source sheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Create a copy of the source sheet to be used as the hi-sheet.
    sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, dvrg As Range
    
    ' Delete existing hi-sheet.
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(HI_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dws Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
            dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' Sort the data in the hi-sheet.
    
    Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    dws.Name = HI_NAME
    If dws.AutoFilterMode Then dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(FIRST_EXPENSES_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim cCol As Long: cCol = dfCell.Column
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        Set drg = .Worksheet.Range(dfCell.EntireRow.Cells(1), _
            .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    Dim drgAddress As String: drgAddress = drg.Address
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = drg.Rows.Count
    Dim cRow As Long: cRow = Int(rCount / 2)
    
    With dws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 drg.Columns(cCol), , xlDescending
        .SetRange drg
        .Header = xlNo
        .Apply
    End With

    Dim Threshold As Double: Threshold = drg.Cells(cRow, cCol).Value
    
    ' Copy the sorted hi-sheet to be used as the lo-sheet.
    
    dws.Copy After:=dws
    
    ' Delete data from the hi-sheet
    
    With drg.Offset(-1).Resize(rCount + 1)
        .AutoFilter cCol, "<" & Threshold
        Set dvrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    
    dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    dvrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    'Application.Goto Reference:=dws.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
    
    ' Reset the object variables to be used with the lo-sheet.
    Set dws = Nothing
    Set drg = Nothing
    Set dvrg = Nothing
    
    ' Delete existing lo-sheet.
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(LO_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dws Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
            dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' Delete data from the lo-sheet
    
    Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' lo-sheet
    dws.Name = LO_NAME
    Set drg = dws.Range(drgAddress)
    
    With drg.Offset(-1).Resize(rCount + 1)
        .AutoFilter cCol, ">=" & Threshold
        Set dvrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    
    dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    dvrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    'Application.Goto Reference:=dws.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
        
    sws.Select
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Offices split by expenses.", vbInformation

End Sub
```